# Displaying ng2-pdf-viewer PDF from stream

Tags: angular

I have a page that uses ng2-pdf-viewer:

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="fileToDownload" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```

There is a Node API that populates that PDF and returns a URL:

```
this.httpClient.post(APIURL, JSON.stringify(body), options).subscribe(
      result => {
        let apiResponse: any = result;
          if (apiResponse.success == 1) {
            this.showPreviewPDF = true;
            let myfileToDownload = sessionStorage.getItem('endPoint') + "downloads/" + apiResponse.file;
            this.httpClient.get(myfileToDownload, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
              .subscribe((file: ArrayBuffer) => {
                this.fileToDownload = new Uint8Array(file);
              });
          }

      },
      error => {

      });
```

Then I get the stream for the PDF. I can see the PDF perfectly on the console network, but Im not able to display it.

I checked several examples, including changing this

```
this.fileToDownload = new Uint8Array(file);
```

by this

```
this.fileToDownload = file;
```

But I still cannot display the PDF on screen. It works fine if I point the PDF to a folder outside Node, but not as a stream.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi K J. In Safari, When inspecting the Network tab, I can see the PDF document and its being streamed perfectly. Im just having issues with displaying it at pdf-viewer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts file create temp url using

```
this.tempurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(streamValue);
```

in you .html file apply this url.

```
 <pdf-viewer
                [src]="blobUrl"
                [rotation]="0"
                [original-size]="false"
                [show-all]="true"
                [fit-to-page]="false"
                [zoom]="1"
                [zoom-scale]="'page-width'"
                [stick-to-page]="false"
                [render-text]="true"
                [external-link-target]="'blank'"
                [autoresize]="true"
                [show-borders]="false"
                style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"
              ></pdf-viewer>
```